# Backbone JS cascading callbacks and best practise

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, parse-platform, callback

I am loving Backbone. My app is growing pretty well but I am faced with the following challenge : the stack of callbacks is getting higher and higher.

I end up calling a function, passing it a few arguments and a callback, which is then passed as the last argument to another function, which then does the same with another function, etc.

I feel this is wrong, as maintaining code for new comers become harder and harder, and it shadows arguments of the callback sometimes 3 to 4 calls down the road, but I can't find any best practise on this.

Is there any guideline regarding passing callbacks as function argument, and callbacks nesting in JS / Backbone? Any piece of advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Promises in JS addresses this exactly... https://www.promisejs.org

Comment: I know about them, but I didn't thought of it as an alternative to callbacks drilling. I'll check your link ASAP. Thanks for the tip